# How to display payment gateway response messages in view - Rails 4, Active Merchant

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, activemerchant

I'm using Active Merchant with Stripe as the payment gateway. Everything works fine except that i don't know how to go about getting the gateway response error messages from Stripe (when a card is declined, invalid etc) to display on the checkout page to the user. I can get a StandardError to be raised that redirects to an error page with the response message but that's it.

**ORDER MODEL**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :order_products
has_many :products, through: :order_products

attr_accessor :card_number, :security_code, :card_expires_on

validate :validate_card, :on => :create

    def validate_card
    unless credit_card.valid? 
      credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
       errors[:base] << message

      end

   end
end

def purchase(basket)

    response = GATEWAY.purchase(Product.total_basket_price(basket)*100, credit_card, purchase_options)
        unless response.success? 
         raise StandardError, response.message



    end
end



def credit_card

    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        :number                 => card_number,
        :first_name             => first_name,
        :last_name              => last_name,
        :verification_value     => security_code,
        :month                  => card_expires_on.month,
        :year                   => card_expires_on.year
        )
end

def purchase_options 
{
    :billing_address => {
        :address1 => address_1,
        :address2 => address_2,
        :city     => city,
        :country  => country_code,
        :zip      => postal_code 
        }
}

end


end
```

**ORDERS CONTROLLER**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

def create



    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    # @product = basket.find(params[:product_id])


    basket.each do |item_id|
        @order.order_products.build(product: Product.find(item_id))
    end

    if @order.save
        if @order.purchase(basket)

            render "show"
        else
            render "failure"
        end
    else
        render "new"


    end
end
```

Can anyone lend a hand, please??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling and help, the working solution was to search for an `error` key within the response params hash and if an error was present add the message to the object errors. Not particularly elegant but it now does what i want.

ORDER MODEL

```
def purchase(basket)

    response = GATEWAY.purchase(Product.total_basket_price(basket)*100, credit_card, purchase_options)

        if response.params.key?('error')

            self.errors.add :base, response.message

            false

        else 
            true

        end 

end
```

ORDERS CONTROLLER

Also switched the order of the `if` statements in the controller so that `def purchase(basket)` runs first before the order is saved, allowing the error message(s) from the response to be caught and displayed.

```
if @order.purchase(basket)
        if @order.save

            render "show"   
        else 

            render "new"


        end
    else
        render "new"


    end
```

VIEW

```
<%= if @order.errors.any?
           @order.errors[:base].to_sentence

end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy!

This is a simple matter of control flow. In Ruby, as in most languages, exceptions interrupt the normal program flow. As your code is written now, `#purchase` is raising an exception when it fails.

That's fine and a perfectly valid design decision. But the code interacting with `#purchase` is this:

```
if @order.purchase(basket)
    render "show"
else
    render "failure"
end
```

That code has no exception handling, so any exception will be caught by Rails, program flow will halt, and you'll get either a detailed error page (in development mode) or a generic 500 error page (in production mode).

Since you profess to be new to Ruby and Rails, a little code substitution might make this clearer:

```
# If #purchase is successful, it evaluates to true.
if true
  render "show"       # 'show' view is rendered as expected. Flow stops.
else
  render "failure"
end

# If #purchase fails, it raises an exception.
if raise StandardError, response.message
  # ^^^ Exception is raised, flow stops here.
  render "show"       # This code is never reached.
else                  # This code is never reached.
  render "failure"    # This code is never reached.
end
```

As I implied in the beginning, though, it's an easy fix once you know what the issue is. You can simply handle the exception with `rescue`. Where you currently have an if/else block, you can swap in an if block and a rescue block:

```
if @order.purchase(basket)
  render 'show'
end
rescue => e
  render 'failure'
```

There's room for improvement here depending on your needs—since you're raising and rescuing `StandardError`, for example, your can't easily distinguish between a network failure and a declined card—but it'll get you moving again.

Comment: Thanks @colinm, that's helped a little. I've tried googling `rescue` and how to use it but haven't found a lot on it.